# Embed XML/RSS feed into website

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, rss

I'm trying to embed these pages into my website.

http://globalnews.ca/regina/feed/

http://weather.gc.ca/rss/city/sk-32_e.xml

I'm not sure exactly how these pages are supposed to work. Are these pages only used for scraping data? I'm not sure how to get the information from these XML/RSS feeds?

Comment: You need to load the data, parse it (with an XML parser) and generate the output you want to send to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

After some more search I discovered that I need to parse them XML in some fashion.  I am using PHP so my first step is to use

```
simplexml_load_file('http://weather.gc.ca/rss/city/sk-32_e.xml');
```

and then read it from an array.

Answer (score -1):

Use Google Feed API. It's pretty simple to get to work, and only needs Javascript.

https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#getting-started

Comment: The Google Feed API is deprecated since December 15th, 2016. See here https://developers.google.com/feed/